# How to add OCRed text to original pdf in gscan2pdf?

Tags: pdf, ocr

I am new to gscan2pdf 0.9.31, and just used it to OCR a scanned pdf.

After saving the pdf, the OCRed text is stored on the top left corner. However I wish  each OCRed character to be added to exactly where it was OCRed from, to make the pdf file text-selectable. Can I do that?

Comment: Three questions: (1) Can you provide a screenshot that illustrates your problem? -- (2) Which OCR engine did you use on your original input file?  -- (3) Which format was your original input file (PDF? JPEG? TIFF? PNG? ...)?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer exactly your question but after experimenting with various programs to achieve what you're looking for, that is a text-selectable scanned pdf, the easiest solution I found is to use PDF XChange viewer through Wine. Just open the scanned pdf, click the OCR button, select the language and other settings. Save when finished.